# How to lint the right filetype for import in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

After installing WebStorm and opening up a existing Vue/TypeScript project with it, I noticed that some file imports haven't been imported and linted correctly by the IDE (but they do via ESLint/webpack)

I use Vue 2.x with composition API and singlefile components.
Under `<script lang="ts">` I import my files with explicit file extensions except for `.ts` files, which I can import without writing the file extension.

In this project, there is a recurring caseof of a `.vue` and a `.ts` file sharing the same name in the same folder, in this Example `App.vue` and `App.ts`.

When in `App.vue` I import `App.ts` like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { someFunction } from './App';

// export defineComponent({
//  ...
```

the IDE shows the exported member in red with a tool tip saying `Element not exported`.
The filepath cannot be resolved and I cannot jump to it via <kbd>Command + Click</kbd> or see types of exported members.

It works again after adding `.ts` extension, but then ESLint/webpack complains. The project works fine so far, it's just WebStorm that seems to have problems resolving the path.

Tried different settings in "Code Style | TypeScript" and googling for a couple hours but couldn't solve it/find anything.

It's my first day trying out WebStorm and I like it so far, but I cannot overcome this issue.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-53277](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53277) for updates.

Unfortunately the only workaround for now is using different names for `.ts` and `.vue` files located in the same directory